# What can I do to stop extra players from joining my Photon Bolt multiplayer game hosted with PlayFab in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon, playfab

I'm currently working on a multiplayer game using Photon Bolt, with PlayFab for hosting a dedicated server.

With my local server implementation (where one instance creates a room as the server and other instances join as clients), everything was working perfectly fine like creating a room and joining players up to the max limit. After implementing PlayFab, I noticed that a ghost player often joins the lobby, and then vanishes after a few seconds. For example, in a room of 8, there are only 7 real players, and the 8th is often a ghost that automatically gets kicked out. This doesn't happen every time, and there aren't any real replication steps. I just set up a room as normal and sometimes this happens, and sometimes it doesn't.

Replication Steps: Unknown
Logs messages: Multiple join calls printed

I want to ask if anyone here ever faced this type of issue while working with PlayFab or multiplayer games in general.

Restrict Ghost/Extra player from joining the lobby